# Origin of the prepositions "on" vs "in" with regard to days and dates in English

Tags: word-choice, etymology, prepositions

The prepositions of time "On, In, and At" are generally described as:

- At - specific time
- On - specific days, dates
- In - period of time

However, I am wondering why we use "on" to refer to a specific day instead of "in" because a day is a period of time. Is this because when something happens within a day we generally "shrink" the entire day to one discrete unit where the event happens? E.g., your birthday is the whole day, even though the actual event is a specific point of time.

Comment: If it was "one discrete unit" of time, then wouldnt we use *at*? I think there is probably no *why* to the usage. It's just there, at present, anyway: preposition usage changes over time.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with *American* English? I thought that British English was the same way.

Comment: @Laurel There is this difference, that AmE often uses no preposition at all before specifying a day, whereas in BrE that's generally not done  except for "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow" and relative expressions such as "last Monday".

Comment: @Lauel and RosieF Yes, the preposition before a day is *optional* in AmE: *I start dance class (on) Monday*. But I'm not sure that the preposition usage is germane to the queshun.

Comment: It does not matter if it is American English or British English, the same question applies.

Comment: @adlsfkj Then I have removed *American* from the title of your question.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 There are differences in the way British and American speakers use these prepositions with time. For example Americans do things *on the weekend* whilst we do them *at the weekend*. But as regards your point - In Britain you can say "I will do it Friday" but it is informal and a lesser register than "on Friday".

Comment: Isn’t it because if we travel on the road then in a mile or so we come to the toll-gate at the bridge? The more relevant to time if the route is by river, rather than road.

The road, the river or the day seem as platforms supporting activity; the distances or periods as containers; the toll and the time as place markers, positions in space and time as well as prepositions.